# speeding up multiple onmouseover events in IE

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom, browser

I have a web page with many (up to 100+) html elements on it.  Each one has an onmouseover event registered to fire to do some logic and rendering depending on which element is hovered over.

I am finding that in IE the more onmouseover events that are regitered the longer they take to fire.  In Firefox the speed is fine and in Chrome even faster!

Does anyone know a solution to this problem.  I thought perhaps registering a single onmousemove event and trying to retrieve the DOM element from the co-ordinates but I'm unsure how to do this or if its just a fudge around the problem.

Comment: Sample code please. 100 elements is not a lot (even for IE). It may be the "some logic" that can be optimized, not the event binding.

Comment: If you tell us what you're trying to accomplish with the event handling maybe someone could offer a more efficient solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attach an onmouseover or mousemove (I think both of these bubble, can't remember) event to the body and when you hover over your actual elements, you can handle what you need to do as it will bubble up to the body where you can handle the element you actually moused over. You can use custom attributes or expando properties of that element to handle what ever you need to do in the mouseover for the specific element.

You should really only be attaching events as you need them and detaching them when you no longer need them. On trivial pages this is probably not required, but in a scenario like yours, it will improve client-side performance. We used to do stuff like this where I worked when we would have thousands of form elements on a page.

My two cents,
nickyt

Comment: That sounds great but how would I identify which element I was hovering over?  I need to do some logic and highlight the element hovered over based on some logic based on its location in the DOM

Comment: The element that you are actually hovering over could be pulled from the IE implementation event.srcElement or all other browsers event's target property. However it would probably make more sense to use a JS framework like jQuery to avoid the cross-browser forking. Hope that helps.

Comment: Great that worked perfectly but its still a bit slow.  As others expected I think I have some other bottleneck as well. Cheers

Comment: If you post a code sample of what appears to be your bottleneck maybe myself or others can help you figure out the issue. Cheers.