# jQuery event bubbling: Get original element mouseover (for table row highlighting)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, event-bubbling

I'm trying to reduce my 'onmouseover' event listeners in my table (in which I highlight rows on hover). I want to do this by attaching an event listener to the entire table instead of each <tr> (that's how I have it now). The reason is that IE is reacting very slow and the only answer I found to this was to reduce the number of event listeners.

Sample code:

```
<table id="myTable">
   <tr>
     <td>Somedata</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Somedata 2</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>Somedata 3</td>
   </tr>       
</table>
```

In this scenario, if I hover over the second <tr>, I understand that the "onmouseover" event bubbles from tr to the table.

How could I find out in my jQuery $('#myTable').mouseover event which tr was hovered and change its css class?

**Edit**: The idea for this comes from this SO question (but unfortunately no source code in the answer): [Speeding Up Multiple OnMouseOver Events in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667118/speeding-up-multiple-onmouseover-events-in-ie)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's called [event delegation](http://www.sitepoint.com/blogs/2008/07/23/javascript-event-delegation-is-easier-than-you-think/).

You're using jQuery which makes it trivial to find the triggering `<tr>` element of the event, via [`closest`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/closest):

```
$('#myTable').mouseover(function(event) {
    var tr = $(event.target).closest('tr');
    // do something with the <tr> element...
})
```

`closest` was in fact written to support event delegation like this. It's what [`live()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) uses internally.

Comment: What is the "e" parameter used for? Is it necessary & what does it represent?

Comment: @Alex: the `e` parameter is the `event` object generated by the `mouseover`. Every user action generates one of these events. See http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html

Comment: @Alex: ps I've edited the answer to use a better var name than `"e"` ;)

Comment: Can’t you just use `$(this)` instead of `$(event.target)`?

Comment: @Timwi $(this) in this case is equivalent to $('#myTable'); event.target is the lowest element on the chain, so finding the closest <tr> will match the element you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the mouseover event to the table but every time you mouseover any child element of the table that function will fire.

```
$('#myTable').mouseover(function(e) {
  $(e.target).parents('tr');
});
```

That will get you the tr of element that was hovered.

Comment: or you could just `$('#myTable tr').mouseover(function(e){ $(e.target); });`

Comment: @Pierre: The preference is usually to have a few delegated or bubbling event handlers, rather than loads of individual handlers wired up directly to elements, so that is not a better option than the one shown.

Comment: @GoneCoding I agree! This was posted a while back before I knew what I know now. Never too old to learn ey!